# Using chown $USER:$USER inside bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, terminal, gnome-terminal, chown

In a small bash script I'm running I am attempting to chown a new directory that is created. I've added:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER /var/www/$sitename
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/$sitename
```

after the line where I mkdir (`sudo mkdir /var/www/$sitename`).

For some reason the chown is not executing. I can execute it manually but when written in the file it doesn't work. I have noticed that "chown" is not highlighted in the same color as "mkdir" and "chmod" but I can't figure out my problem.

Why doesn't chown work here?

Is it an issue with `$USER:$USER`?

**EDIT** 
Here is the full script. How would I chown the file to whichever non root user executed the script?

```
#!/bin/sh
#!/bin/bash
# New Site

cd /etc/apache2/sites-available/
echo "New site name (test.my):"
read sitename
echo "<VirtualHost *:80>

        ServerAdmin admin@$sitename

    ServerName $sitename

        ServerAlias $sitename

    DocumentRoot /var/www/$sitename

        <Directory />
                Options FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
        </Directory>
        <Directory /var/www/$sitename>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride All
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined


</VirtualHost>" > $sitename.conf
sudo mkdir /var/www/$sitename
sudo chown $USER:$USER /var/www/$sitename
echo USER is $USER
sudo chmod 775 /var/www/$sitename
sudo a2ensite $sitename.conf
sudo apachectl restart
echo "New site created"
```

Comment: Is there a group named $USER? `getent group $USER`

Comment: `$USER` variable is set during interactive login. How do you run your script - from login session or using cron or from daemon?

Comment: Check if the USER variable is even seen by the script. If you add a line to your script that says `echo USER is $USER`, what does it print out?

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Evidently, `USER is root`. With the edit I've made do you think you can explain how to chown the file to whichever non-root user executes the script?

Comment: @myaut I run it manually from the terminal.

Comment: Maybe try `$(id -nu)` instead of `$USER`?

Comment: @Celada Like `$(id -nu):$(id -nu)` or simply `$(id -nu)` in place of both?

Comment: @BrassApparatus I guess technically you'd want to use `$(id -nu):$(id -ng)` to get the user and the group.

Comment: Try using $U or anything else, but not $USER, because this variable is special for sudo. See `man sudo` section `ENVIRONMENT`.

Comment: Use `chmod user: <file>` to `chown` to the user and his primary group.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If for some reason, `$USER` is not set, you can use the `id` command to obtain the identity of the real user.  So the first time you use the `$USER` variable, you can use the shell expansion to supply a default value.  Change the `chown` line in your script to:

```
sudo chown "${USER:=$(/usr/bin/id -run)}:$USER" "/var/www/$sitename"
```

If `USER` is empty or unset when this is run, bash will set the `USER` variable to the output of `/usr/bin/id -run`.

Answer (score 5):

When I calling my script with `sudo` it would set `$USER` to root.

```
$ sudo ./myscript.sh
```

I tried the `chown ${USER:=$(/usr/bin/id -run)}:$USER /var/www/$sitename` but it would still return root.

I found if I used `who` with `awk` I was able to get the current user that called the script with `sudo`.

```
currentuser=$(who | awk '{print $1}')}
chown -R $currentuser:$currentuser /var/www/$sitename`
```

Comment: To prevent setting `currentuser` (sometime) with multiline users, use `$(who | awk 'NR==1{print $1}')` instead.

Comment: I am trying to change /usr to my user:  `chown -R $currentuser:$currentuser /usr`  - does not work - still shows root:root

Comment: (1) `who` is not guaranteed to produce any output.  (2) If it does, there is no guarantee that the first line of output identifies the current user.  What if somebody `ssh`’ed into your system?  What if you are `ssh`’ed into some other system? (3) ```logname``` seems to be more reliable.

Answer (score 2):

In order to simplify the problem and since your are getting the variable sitename, why don't you read a username variable?

With that you'd make sure that the script execution is not dependent on the environmental variables made available the way the script is executed.

Answer (score 1):

The [accepted answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/205007/531356) by @tim-cutts would not work if you call the script itself with `sudo`:

```bash
sudo ./myscript.sh
```

A more simple version of [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304761/531356) would be to use `logname`:

```bash
curuser=$(logname)
chown $curuser:$curuser /var/www/$sitename
```

Comment: Note that the script in the question is executed with `/bin/sh` as the shell. If that shell does not set the `USER` variable, Tim's code would call `id` to figure out the username. Under what circumstances would `logname` get the username right and `id` get it wrong? Would the shell need to set `USER` to the wrong username for that to be the case? What do _you_ mean by "not work"? Are you expecting the user to be reported as root or the invoking user in your example?

Comment: Sorry for the tone in my last comment (I just re-read it). What I was fishing for is merely an explanation of the problem that you see and an explanation of your solution, taking into account that since you refer to Tim's answer, you would need to clarify the circumstances that his answer gets it wrong and what "wrong" actually means.

Comment: @Kusalananda: The explanation is right there in the first paragraph. OK, yes, the script in the question contains multiple `sudo` commands, so it’s ‘ ‘clearly’ ’ meant to be run by a non-root user. But what if somebody inadvertently runs the script itself under ``sudo``? Then the `id` command (as used by Tim Cutts) would return “root” and not, as (presumably) desired, the name of the logged-in user.

Comment: @Kusalananda: OK, now it’s *my* turn to re-read and re-write/clarify.  Hogcryat’s answer (above) links to [Eric James Deiter’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/304761/80216), and the explanation is in the first paragraph of ***Eric’s*** answer.

Comment: @Kusalananda it is just as Reinstate Monica says. It is an improvement to Eric's answer in the case the script was called with `sudo` (which I know is not the question's original intention). I would have liked to comment under Eric's answer but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Hogcryat: If you're going to abbreviate my name, please abbreviate it as ''G-Man''.

Answer (score 0):

There is only a tiny fault I think. sudo opens a new shell for executing the command and after sudo the user is root. So maybe you should use something like this:

> MYUSER=$USER
>
> sudo chown $MYUSER:$MYUSER

as i think MYUSER is not systemspezific overwritten and shall work.

Comment: The variable is evaluated before the command is executed, so your suggested alternative would make no difference. (Try it with `echo chown...` and see.)