# chown doesn't work through script

Tags: bash, shell-script, scripting, chown

I have a script:

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/Folder
```

The chown doesn't seem to execute.

If I just write the above line from terminal ,it runs fine though!

I have read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183183/using-chown-useruser-inside-bash-script) but doesn't help.

The name of the script is mysetup.sh and I am running as  `sudo sh mysetup.sh`.

It doesn't give any output.

If I run it like `sudo bash -x mysetup.sh` , I am receiving:

`sudo chown -R root:root /opt/Folder`

This problem does not related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/183183/using-chown-useruser-inside-bash-script),since the USER is set.

Comment: What's the exit code after running? Could you `/bin/bash -x` it to trace what is going on?

Comment: @thrig:Just write `/bin/bash -x ` from a terminal?It shows many lines and I can't see something related.I tried also `#! /bin/bash -x ` inside the script but where do I see the messages?

Comment: What he means is to run the script using `bash -x scriptname`. Or put `set -x` in the script itself.

Comment: @Barmar:Hello , I updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to change the contents of `/opt/Folder` to *your own* userid, aren't you.

Here's your command once again:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER /opt/Folder
```

This works from the command line because the `$USER` variable is evaluated before the command is executed, and it is therefore executed as this (assuming your username is `george`):

```
sudo chown -R george:george /opt/Folder
```

On the other hand, when you run a command with `sudo`, amongst other things the `$USER` variable takes the value of the target user, which in this case is `root`. So by running `sudo bash mysetup.sh` you are running `mysetup.sh` as root, so the command runs with `$USER` set to `root` and is evaluated like this

```
sudo chown -R root:root /opt/Folder
```

The solution in your case is to avoid running the entire script itself under `sudo`, and let the script use `sudo` where necessary to run specific commands with elevated privileges. In other words, use `bash mysetup.sh` instead of `sudo bash mysetup.sh`.

Comment: Your recommendation is what he was doing in the original version of the question.

Comment: @George Isn't this what you were doing originally? You've edited the question, but it originally had the `sudo` command inside the script.

Comment: @Barmar:I have (and had ) the sudo command insided the script but I was running the script also with sudo.

Answer (score -3):

You haven't mentioned your distribution and version of Linux (or unix) you are running, so I am going on a tangent here, assuming this following line is in your `/etc/sudoers`

```
Defaults requiretty
```

hence you can not run sudo without a tty. And when you try to run it from the script, your `sudo` doesn't run, effectively crippling your `chown` command.

Try adding `-t` or `-tt` switches to your sudo command. These will create a pseudo terminal to run your `sudo` chain of commands and hopefully will succeed but this option has its side effects as well, not to be discussed here. You can search for them if you want to.

If you have access to `sudo` configuration, you take out the line mentioned above for the best of solutions but with this action, you are eliminating one level of barricades, despite how weak it is.

Comment: Firstly any script run by the user is going to inherit the tty it was launched from. Second `sudo`'s `-t` flag has nothing to do with ttys, you're thinking of `ssh`.